# Giving standard user access to hard drive

Tags: mount, permissions, hard-drive

I am using Ubuntu 16.04. Before I installed Ubuntu I disconnected one hard drive, and left only the hard drive that I intended to install Ubuntu on. I installed Ubuntu and created two other standard users. On admin account I have no problem accessing hard drive. But when I try to use standard users I get either a pop up window where I have to type in my admin password or just a pop up window where it says I am denied access. I tried using Users and Groups but I got nowhere with that.

Here is what I get when i type in `sudo blkid`

```
/dev/dm-1: UUID="0bc12e6b-4c2f-423d-a86c-23c4bad50d57" TYPE="swap"
/dev/sda1: LABEL="Seagate" UUID="EC581FBA581F830E" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="5e06dee1-02"
/dev/sdb1: UUID="d3ac8f35-33f1-4431-9f7f-d108e00d5223" TYPE="ext2" PARTUUID="f6200ce9-01"
/dev/sdb5: UUID="CcsQy0-XSse-KKSi-OCAN-kEH2-OHEP-Qm3XEA" TYPE="LVM2_member" PARTUUID="f6200ce9-05"
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: UUID="df7692a7-d8c9-4264-a5d4-6d425bc097eb" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1: UUID="0bc12e6b-4c2f-423d-a86c-23c4bad50d57" TYPE="swap"
```

Output of `mount`

```
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=1918904k,nr_inodes=479726,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=394464k,mode=755)
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,release_agent=/lib/systemd/systemd-cgroups-agent,name=systemd)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls,net_prio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/pids type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=25,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,relatime)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,relatime)
/dev/sdb1 on /boot type ext2 (rw,relatime,block_validity,barrier,user_xattr,acl)
vmware-vmblock on /run/vmblock-fuse type fuse.vmware-vmblock (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=394464k,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000)
/home/.ecryptfs/vlada/.Private on /home/vlada type ecryptfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,ecryptfs_fnek_sig=1ef6fc068c39b13d,ecryptfs_sig=607f8af866ecc53a,ecryptfs_cipher=aes,ecryptfs_key_bytes=16,ecryptfs_unlink_sigs)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
/dev/sda1 on /media/vlada/Seagate type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096,uhelper=udisks2)
```

Comment: please can you paste the output of `mount`in your question? can you show the output of `ls -la hdd` where hdd is the path to the disk drive?

Comment: @NickSillito I added mount output. I  hope i understood you correctly.

Comment: It looks to me like you have encrypted your home disk? This isnt something that I've ever done on Ubuntu so dont rely on my opinion, but reading [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedHome) I assume that you cant read this directory without the admin user logging in (sorry -- I am only guessing here -- other people can answer this better than me)